# Error in application scoped style in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml

I just want to create application defined `Style`:

```
<Application x:Class="Customer_UI.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <style>
        </style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**`ERROR: style is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project`**

Comment: it's `Style` not `style`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, try write `Style` tag like this: `<Style ... />`. Secondly, you must add `TargetType` or the `Key` for your Style, because `ResourcesDictionary` it is a Dictionary and there is can not be elements without the key. The Key in this case it's a hash, what needed for not ordered Dictionary.

Example:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">

    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

For more information, see this:

[`MSDN: Styling and Templating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: yeah i had bad letter casing, ty

Answer (score 0):

```
<Application x:Class="Customer_UI.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
       <Style>
       </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because for Style must be set the `Key` or `TargetType`. You can check yourself.